# Prevent first input row being deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been messing around with dynamic input fields and everything is working great. The only issue I'm having is stopping the first `input_line` from being deleted.

So pretty much every `input_line` (refer to my fiddle for exmaple) should be able to be removed except the first one, that one should always stay.

Illustration:

[image]

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1"><input type="button" class="duplicate" value="duplicate"><input type="button" class="remove" value="remove">
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line');

    $('.add').click(function () {
        var newElement = blank_line.clone(true).hide();
        $('form').append(newElement);
        $(newElement).slideDown();
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
        $(this).parent().clone().hide().insertAfter($(this).parent().after()).slideDown();
        $('.input_line').last().before($('.add'));
        input = input + 1;
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parent().slideUp(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('.input_line').last().before($('.add'));
        input = input - 1;
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqgaswdy/1/)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the remove when there's one row, else show it:

http://jsfiddle.net/gqgaswdy/23/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     'use strict';
     var input = 1,
          blank_line = $('.input_line');
     var removing = false;
     $('.remove').hide();

     $('.add').click(function () {
          var newElement = blank_line.clone(true).hide();
          $('form').append(newElement);
          $(newElement).slideDown();
          $('.remove').show();
     });

     $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
          $(this).parent().clone().hide().insertAfter($(this).parent().after()).slideDown();
          $('.input_line').last().before($('.add'));
          $('.remove').show();
          input = input + 1;
     });

     $('form').on('click', '.remove', function () {
          if (removing) {
                return;
          } else {
                if ($('.input_line').length <= 2) $('.remove').hide();
                $(this).parent().slideUp(function () {
                     $(this).remove();
                     removing = false;
                });
                $('.input_line').last().before($('.add'));
                input = input - 1;
          }
          removing = true;
     });
});
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with a Fiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: I've just mocked up your code in a fiddle and it doesn't work in the way I illustrated in my question.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating but that still doesn't seem to work, it just disables every remove button.

Comment: Not sure if we're looking at the same fiddle.. I updated it a moment ago.  Works for me in firefox and chrome

Comment: Yeah that updated version seems to be working, the only problem is if you smam the remove button at the top to remove a bunch of rows at a time it will sometimes remove the first one. A fix for this?

Comment: How about maybe just hiding the first remove button and then only showing it for the rest?

Comment: You could do it that way too.  I wasn't able to reproduce the problem you described.  Not even sure what "smam" means.. but try the updated jfiddle and tell me if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/gqgaswdy/11/

Comment: Sorry I mean't spam. That's actually pretty clever disabling all of them at a time while it's removing one. But I'm wanting to move away from buttons when I style this properly and perhaps use icons etc. So I won't be able to use the disabled attribute. Could you try a version hiding the first and showing the rest?

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to accept your answer until I noticed that.

Comment: You can still spam the remove button, even though it works majority of the time I hate cutting corners. Try doing multiple tests spamming the remove button. :/

Comment: Yeah.. it's that darned animation :-)  try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/gqgaswdy/23/

Comment: Haha, it's that "darned" animation that makes it look cool! :) I think you have it though, I have tried multiple spam test and it seems to work every time. Great Job and that for being patient with me, got there in the end! :-)

Comment: Just a quick question, on like 26 why didn't you use a curly brace for the if statement? JSLint doesn't seem to like that... & when I add the curly brace it won't work, why?

Comment: It wasn't working earlier for me, odd. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Just would like to show you how easy it is to create such behavior in frameworks actually intended for databinding (which jquery is not, so you have to write a lot of additional/unnecessary logic) with example of knockout.js

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prowseed/eeLt06yo/)

```
<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.name">
    <button data-bind="click: $root.duplicate">Duplicate</button>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.remove, enable: $root.rows().length > 1">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="button" data-bind="click: addRow">add Row</button>

var row = function(name) {         
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}; 

function TableModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addRow = function() {
        self.rows.push( new row('') );
    };
    self.duplicate = function(a) {
        self.rows.push( new row(a.name()) );
    };
    self.remove = function(a) {
        self.rows.remove(a);
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new TableModel());
```

Comment: very cool.  thanks for highlighting another, perhaps more appropriate, technology

Comment: @Maciej Kwas I hadn't even heard of knockout until now, it does cut the code down dramatically. Maybe I'll have a further look into it, looks rather interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add new function like this:

```
function HideRemoveButton(){
        if($('.input_line').length <= 1){
            $('.remove').hide()
        }
        else{
            $('.remove').show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with a Fiddle to demonstrate this?